# Does short-code slow down my WordPress site?

Tags: shortcode

I use many shortcodes on my sites. Generally, I use 5-10 shortcodes per posts. As WordPress is flexible and customizable, but due to the lack of wide technical knowledge, I have to use many plugins on my site. Many of the plugins rely on shortcodes. Along with that I also uses shortcodes to achieve a professional look.

Is it bad for speed and performance?

Comment: "That depends." - Usually stuff like this doesn't influence site speed **if you have proper caching** enabled

Comment: It depends entirely on what those shortcodes and plugins do.

Comment: I have Autoptimize, Wp super cache enable on my site for caching. Along with that, I use Cloudflare CDN. Don't know if they relate to the proper caching you are talking about.- @kero

Comment: @Bikram If you have WP Super Cache enabled, this will most likely not influence your speed - as WP Super Cache uses full page cache (so no PHP/shortcode/... gets executed, but it is rendered only once). Site speed in WordPress is a huge topic, there should be a lot of resources about it on the net

Answer (score 1):

No. The use of short code does not slow your website.

It is just a function call.

However, the code itself, may be slowing your website page load time.

It depends upon the specific code that is executed.